# Tying hints for spacy tokens

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, spacy, type-hinting, python-typing

I am having trouble getting the typing hints to work for the spacy token types.  The code runs fine,  but the IDE (VSCode) reports that Doc, Span and Token are "unknown import symbols".  (The type for the Language type is correctly found)

To recreate:

- Create a new python 3.8.10 project and virtual environment
- `pip install spacy`
- create a new file called `main.py' with the following content

```
import spacy
from spacy.language import Language
from spacy.tokens import Doc, Span, Token

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc: Doc = nlp("some stuff")
```

- I'm using VSCode so I enabled type checking by adding the following code to my `.vscode/settings.json` file.

```
{
  "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
  "python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "basic",
}
```

Comment: I've got the same issue - did you post anything about it on github?

Comment: re. github I did not.   I think it's because spacy is written in C so the hints aren't coming through.  Maybe it needs a stub file?

Comment: I agree and it seems that they are working on adding stub files. See the release notes that was just published; https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/releases/tag/v3.1.2. So it should be fixed in `v3.1.2` which was released a moment ago